# Supplied parameters do not match any type of target

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

Since I am not using a DB and am creating my own data for a demo project SOF had not been able to help.

I have the following error when I hover over the method:

[image: Service]

Which gets it methods from the following:

[image: service]

What is confusing is that this method works just fine and is the exact same implementation.

[image: working code]

Constructor:

[image: constructor]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self explanatory, you have to pass `books` collection to `getAllAvailableFictionBooks` & `getAllAvailableProgrammingBooks` method.

You're directly calling `getAllAvailableFictionBooks` method without passing parameters. Rather I'd say call `getAllAvailableFictionBooks` & `getAllAvailableProgrammingBooks` from `getAllBooks()` method. And it should look like below.

```
this.bookService.getAllBooks().forEach((books) => {
   this.allBooks = books;
   this.availableFictionBooks = this.bookService.getAllAvailableFictionBooks(books);
   this.availableProgrammingBooks = this.bookService.getAllAvailableProgrammingBooks(books);
});
```

Comment: @Drew1208 what should I look for, does it got worked?